# SolrJ missing embedded package

Tags: maven, solr

I am trying to use SolrJ with EmbeddedSolrServer but i when i looked in the downloaded library it didnt have the embedded package org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.This is my dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run embedded solr, you need to have basically all of solr, which means you need to also add the solr-core dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```